# rest api and json parsing codeigniter

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How do, I implement (codeigniter) rest API that outputs ajax with JSON. I'm unsure how to use the REST API for deleting. How to delete a  JSON item from a database with REST API.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an big issue. You can perform it once you done it.

```
function user_delete()
{
    // delete a user and respond with a status/errors
}
```

This is fair enough for the delete

---

To format data with JSON, add parameters to URL like below

[image]

> **And i recommended you to learn about [Working with RESTful Services in CodeIgniter](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814)**

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @Abdulla is fair enough, but forces you to use other extensions. If you want to, you can make rest server by yourself. For example, endpoint could be like this:

`DELETE www.example.com/index.php/api/user/1`

and controller could be something like this:

```
<?php
class Api extends CI_Controller {

    public function user($id)
    {
        $user = User::getById($id);
        if ($this->input->method() == 'delete') {
            $user->delete();
            /* And example json output */
            $this->output
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(array('user' => $user)));
        }
    }
}
```